# Writing proper javadoc with @see?

Tags: java, javadoc

How do I use the `@see` javadoc properly?

My intention is to have an abstract class with abstract methods. These methods have javadoc comments.
Now if I extend the abstract class, I override the methods and want to use `@see`.

But for all params, eg for `return` the `@see` link does not seem to work. Eclipse still complains that `expected @return tag`.

So how can I use this?

```
public abstract class MyBase {
  protected abstract void myFunc();
}

class MyImpl extends MyBase {

  /**
   * @see MyBase#myFunc()
   */
  @Override
  protected void myFunc() { .. }
}
```

Comment: It works for me. I can hover and F2 on MyImpl.myFunc and see the javadoc I write on MyBase.myFunc.

Comment: "@see" does not mean - no need to document here.  And mostly it does not mean link to - for that purpose @link may be use as outlined in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915992/how-to-reference-a-method-in-javadoc

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For the purpose of including the documentation from a superclass you should use `{@inheritDoc}` not `@see`.

Then you get the docs of the superclass. You can add to it, and you can override stuff like `@param` and `@return` if you need to.

```
public abstract class MyBase {
  /**
   * @param id The id that will be used for...
   * @param good ignored by most implementations
   * @return The string for id
   */
  protected abstract String myFunc(Long id, boolean good);
}

class MyImpl extends MyBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   * @param good is used differently by this implementation
   */
  @Override
  protected String myFunc(Long id, boolean good) { .. }
}
```