# How to make javadoc about the object's indirect fields?

Tags: java, javadoc, software-design

For example, if i have MyObject with fields SomeThing getFieldOne() SomeThing getFieldTwo() whatever, it is obvious, that while javadocking getFieldOne() and getFieldTwo() , i write there an info about the fields of MyObject retuned.

But what to do, if sime fields are not in MyObject directly via getters avaible, but i must call a static adapter like:
ObjectContainer.getFieldThree(myObject) ?

The info about the fieldTree is logically related to MyObject, howewer it is no getter method there by design( do not ask me why, i have not designed it , i just want to determine the best way to comment that).

Comment: Use an [`@see`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011291/usage-of-see-in-javadoc) or `@link`? Or explain exactly what you want to see in the javadoc.

Comment: Yes good hint with links. I could use those links to ObjectContainer JavaDoc from MyObject Javadoc. <br> I want let a user, reading a JavaDoc about MyObject, know, that there exist a fieldTree, what is logically related to MyObject, and to get it, you must call ObjectContainer.getFieldThree(myObject)

Answer (score 0):

In a scenario like this, `SomeThing` does not necessarily have a dependency on `ObjectContainer`, and thus shouldn't know about the logic or interface of this other class. For this reason, it should not be part of `SomeThing`'s JavaDoc.

I would create a **separate JavaDoc** for `ObjectContainer`, explaining the functionality, and in addition to that, create a separate how-to guide on how to use the two classes and other relevant ones in combination, referring to the JavaDoc. This could have a **'cookbook' style**, as it is common for many libraries or frameworks, explaining certain use cases and scenarios.

Comment: Again: I want let a user, reading a JavaDoc about MyObject, know, that there exist a fieldTree, what is logically related to MyObject, and to get it, you must call ObjectContainer.getFieldThree(myObject)